# What does unsupported configuration - prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers mean?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I got this error and I don't understand why do we need a reuse identifier?

Comment: You should read the documentation for `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I did but I got more confused that's why am seeking for help.

Comment: Your question is vague. Update your question with more details. What do you understand? What part don't you understand?

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView is kind of collection view. These views can represent arrays consisted of thousands items.

If you just create and keep in-memory a view for each item in an array, your memory can be easily overloaded. To handle that, collection view use so-called reusable views - they keep a number of views (let's say 15-20 views), and redraw them in accordance with incoming array items. The reusable views are very similar to each other, in fact they are the same view with the same labels and images, and we merely change content of this labels and images to represent particular item in our data.

However sometimes the data behind each item should be represented differently, it can be distinct set of labels, views and whatever else. To cover this situation there are pools of reusable views. You then tell collection views that to represnt item of type 'A' you need a reusable view of type 'A_cell', and collection views create (if needed) and take corresponding view with required set of subviews.

So reffering back to your question, the cell identifier is a type of a cell, that says `UITableView` which pool of reusable views (`UITableViewCell`) to use and what kind of `UITableViewCell` should be created.

Hope, it will help.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you very much.